# Running Python script in Scripts from different working directory in Windows

Tags: windows, script, python, path

I have `pip install`ed a library ([intelhex](https://github.com/bialix/intelhex)) with [Python](https://www.python.org/) 3.5.1, which also places a few scripts in the `Scripts` subdirectory of the Python installation:

```
>dir "%pythonpath%"\hex2*
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-ABCD

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts

09.10.2016  08:13             4.698 hex2bin.py
09.10.2016  08:13             4.563 hex2dump.py
               2 File(s)          9.261 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  55.359.901.696 bytes free
```

One could assume that `PYTHONPATH` mentioned in the [Python on Windows documentation for environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) might be used for searching scripts, but Python does not find the script if the working directory is another:

```
>python hex2bin.py flash.hex
python: can't open file 'hex2bin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is intended only as search path for `import`ing modules : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath

Is there a method to use a given path as search path for the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://pythonhosted.org/IntelHex/part1-3.html#note-for-windows-users

### Note for Windows users

> Please note that for historical reasons IntelHex library doesn’t use setuptools for installation task, therefore we don’t create exe-wrappers for helper scripts as hex2bin.py, bin2hex.py and other mentioned in this documentation (see section Convenience Scripts).
>
> You can find these scripts in your python Script directory (usually C:\PythonXY\Scripts). You need either to create batch file to run them, or use Python interpreter:

```
python C:\PythonXY\Scripts\hex2bin.py ...
```

First ensure that you've changed directories to the current directory that has "hex2bin.py"

seeing this current error makes me believe you aren't

> python: can't open file 'hex2bin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  (you)

```
python hex2bin.py
```

Now if this throws no errors at you, then attempt to run it with args

```
python hex2bin.py HexFile.hex
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not how the script can be run from inside its directory, but rather if there is a way to provide Python with this directory other than specifying it in the path to the script.